# How to Use Arduino Wifi Shield To Receive/Send Info

Tags: arduino-uno

I am doing an engineering project where I am using an Arduino Uno to try to open a window with a motor when the device is activated. I want to activate it by using a phone to somehow send it a command to “turn on.” I have tried to use the ESP8266 but couldn’t get it working and now have an Arduino Wifi Shield but am very confused on how to use it to do this task. I am new to understanding Arduino so any help would be appreciated.

I found a tutorial on how to connect the wifi shield to internet on the arduino website but am not sure what I would do after this.

Thanks!

Comment: it would be almost the same as using the ESP8266 .... what problems did you have with the ESP8266?

Comment: ESP8266 is not easy for beginner,  Arduino Wifi Shield is retired.
If you use either ESP8266 or  Arduino Wifi, You can control via Web. There are a lot of examples about control via web on Internet. 
However, there is a very simple way to control Arduino via Web, use PHPoC WiFi shield. This shield is pretty easy to use (plug and play), It has built in web apps (can be customized). See [this example](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/phpoc_man/arduino-websocket-056f16)

Comment: use Blynk service or similar